# height not extending for full page

Tags: css

I have the CSS below

```
html, body {
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0 0;
    background:#444;
    height:100%;
} 

#page {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 0;
    height:100%;
    background: url(imgs/bk.png) repeat-y;
}
```

but it doesn't extend my background to the whole end of the layout, just shows my body background color of `#444444` through.

Any help is appreciated please. The website is located at http://www.benfolio.net/new/

EDIT: *SOLVED*
I went out with sme mates and came back for a fresh look at it, first change I made fixed it, the change are below.
`html, body {
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0 0;
    background:#444;
}`

`#page {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 0;
    height:100%;
    background: url(imgs/bk.png) repeat-y;
    overflow:hidden;
}`

Simply took 'height:100%' out of the html,body section and it then defaulted to just 100% for the page div.
Thanks for the help given

Answer (score 2):

Give `#page` the style `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: that doesn't work, just cuts off the rest of my content where the background ends halfway down the page, cheers anyway tho.

Comment: @ben Clarify a little, because flipping the value from `overflow: visible` to `overflow: hidden` on Firebug here definitely worked.

Comment: @yi jiang, please go to http://www.benfolio.net/new/yi/ for an example of what i mean when 'overflow:hidden;'

Answer (score 0):

Change #page to

```
#page {
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: -450px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(imgs/bk.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: thanks but no luck either, that just centered the page but didnt add the background to the height needed

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I went out with sme mates and came back for a fresh look at it, first change I made fixed it, the change are below.

`html, body { margin:0 0; padding:0 0; background:#444; }`

`#page { width: 900px; margin: 0 0; height:100%; background: url(imgs/bk.png) repeat-y; overflow:hidden; }`

Simply took 'height:100%' out of the html,body section and it then defaulted to just 100% for the page div. Thanks for the help given